# How can I troubleshoot a MATSHITA UJ8A0ASW optical drive which yelds different errors in different burning softwares?

Tags: compact-disc, burning, optical-drive, cd-burning

I'm having problems with the optical drive MATSHITA UJ8A0ASW installed on my laptop ASUS N53SV. The driver is Microsoft's 6.1.7601.18514, file version 6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255), I can't find any update for it in the laptop's or the drive's manufacturer websites.

In Windows 7 Home Premium I tried to burn an iso image using Windows Disc Image Burner, InfraRecorder, running isoburn.exe (the process of Windows Disc Image Burner) from an elevated command prompt, using InfraRecorder with administration privileges, ImgBurn with administrator privileges and again Windows Disc Image Burner directly from the administrator account. In Debian/Linux I tried XfceBurn.

In all cases InfraRecorder and XfceBUrn completed the burning procedure but the disc was still empty, using Windows Disc Image Burner yielded `error:0x0AA0301` and using ImgBurn yielded "Power Calibration Area Error".

I ran Microsoft's Fix It utility to check the writing capabilities of the drive but the program didn't find any problem with the drive.

If I ever used this computer to burn any other optical media it was a long time ago and I don't remember doing so.

I already burned my disc using another computer with Windows 8 and ImgBurn, I would like to know which kind of system check I can perform to verify what's the problem with the Panasonic drive in my laptop.

How can I know if there is a driver or settings problem or if I need to buy a new optical drive?

Comment: I ran Microsoft's dev-con utility and checked the system register, no lower or upper filters values are acive on the device. Also, I didn't troubleshoot extensively in Debian/Linux, but the drive misbehaved in that operating system too.

Comment: The laptop's BIOS (Aptio's EFI firmware) is updated to the last release distributed by the laptop's manufacturer.